# PHP OOP database connect

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, oop

I have just started learning the concept of Object oriented programming and I've written this class with functions.

It works fine, but I'm interested in knowing if I have done this correctly...

Here is my code:

```
class Database{
    const DB_HOSTNAME = 'localhost';
    const DB_USERNAME = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = 'password';
    const DB_NAME = 'shop';
    protected $_db_connect;
    protected $_sql;
    protected $_result;
    protected $_row;

    function db_connect(){
        $this->_db_connect = mysql_connect(self::DB_HOSTNAME,self::DB_USERNAME,self::DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    function slect_db(){
        mysql_select_db(self::DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    function sql(){
        $this->_sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    }

    function query(){
        $this->_result = mysql_query($this->_sql);
    }

    function fetch_array(){
        while($this->_row = mysql_fetch_array($this->_result)){
            $username = $this->_row['user_USERNAME'];

            echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>".$username."</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }

    function db_close(){
        mysql_close($this->_db_connect);
    }
}

$database = new Database();
$database->db_connect();
$database->slect_db();
$database->sql();
$database->query();
$database->fetch_array();
$database->db_close();
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: always use singleton design pattern when creating database access for better performance

Comment: I don't think this lends itself to good OO design. Consider that the class you have written is not particularly generic, since your database connection details are just hard-coded constants. Also, the only SQL statement that this class can execute is `SELECT * FROM users`. Is this the intention? I'd consider extending this class with other classes that contain specific SQL, or making the SQL function accept a SQL query string. Also, your database class should not be doing the view rendering (in fetch_array). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: Questions like this are more suited for the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 14):

Please use PDO or MySQLi as it's more secure and mysql_* functions are deprecated as stated above, I've provided some generic code using PDO to help you with that new venture. As stated in the comments, you really shouldn't be echoing out the data if you're looking for an object oriented design, what you should be doing is after you do the query, return the rows that you fetched and from there use something such as a foreach loop to then display your data. Doing your database class this way will also make sure that multiple database connections aren't open at once! Note, this code is just for you to reference, and should be tested before use in production or anything live.

config.php:

```
<?php
    //Enter your database connection details here.
    $host = 'localhost'; //HOST NAME.
    $db_name = 'databasename'; //Database Name
    $db_username = 'root'; //Database Username
    $db_password = ''; //Database Password

    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
    }
?>
```

database.class.php:

```
<?php
    class database
    {
        function __construct($pdo)
        {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
        }

        function getData()
        {
            $query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM database');
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    require_once 'database.class.php';
    $db = new database($pdo);
    $rows = $db->getData();
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to improve the way you connect to databases using autoloading and dependency injection containers. Here is a way of using [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn) to connect to your database while being sure there is only one connection opened and not having to manually require files throughout your application.

I will cover only PDO and Auryn here. There are other dependency injection containers and notably the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension to connect to database, but the content should help you using another container if you wish to do so.

**The database class**

Having a database class is superfluous. The `\PDO` class is already providing all necessary methods to query the database. Having a database class makes you repeat the functions it provides and limits your actions (or makes you create many functions) when you want to for example use multiple different fetch styles depending on your needs in a specific method.

**Dependency Injection**

If you haven't already, have a [read on dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). The point is that when a class needs to access the database, it should not have to bother constructing the `\PDO` object, it should be constructed with it:

```
class Mapper {
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function createFromId($id) {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM foo WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->execute([
            ":id" => $id,
        ]);
        return $stmt->fetchObject();
    }
}
```

Notice that I directly pass the `\PDO` object, not a wrapper class. That way, I always have access to all of its capabilities, not only a subset of user-defined functions.

**Dependency Injection Container**

A dependency injection container helps build your classes, giving them the objects they need, and giving you great flexibility on how to actually build those objects. Here I'll only focus on configuring and *sharing* a `\PDO` object through the use of Auryn.

I assume you have installed the required Auryn class, the easier way is using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). This is out of the scope of this answer, there are multiple resources on how to use it.

- Create the injector

  ```
  $injector = new \Auryn\Injector();
  ```
- Define the `\PDO` class parameters

  ```
  $injector->define("PDO", [
      ":dsn" => "mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=dbname",
      ":username" => "user",
      ":passwd" => "passwd",
      ":options" => [
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
      ],
  ]);
  ```

  You can either write the configuration parameters directly here, or get them from a config file. I like having a config.ini file and using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to get my configuration options, as I can easily switch databases by editing a config file.
- Share the `\PDO` object

  ```
  $injector->share("PDO");
  ```

  This part is *really* important. This lines makes the injector give the same `\PDO` object every time it is tasked with constructing a class that needs a connection. Note that the order of the lines is not important, you can share the class before defining it, only make sure to create you database needing classes after writing both those lines.
- Create your objects

  ```
  $mapper = $injector->make("Mapper");
  ```

  That's it. The injector will create your mapper object, creating the `\PDO` object if it haven't already been, passing the existing instance if it has.

**Autoloading**

Assuming you have used composer, you can make use of its great autoloader. Otherwise you can also roll you own [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

The point here is to stop having `require()` everywhere in your code, especially if you have complex class hierarchies, which you should have in a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) compliant class system.

**Wrapping up**

With this set up, you now can use the `\PDO` object in your classes while being assured there will only be one instance per request, without the need to require files everywhere, and without using a singleton anti-pattern.

Comment: nice and simple explanation

Answer (score -1):

```
$database = new Connection();
class Connection
{
 function __construct()
 {
    switch($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
    {
        case 'path':
            $this->host = 'hostname';
            $this->user = 'username';
            $this->passwd = 'password';
            $this->database = 'dbname';
            break;
        default :
            $this->host = 'localhost';
            $this->user = 'root';
            $this->passwd = 'root';
            $this->database = 'dbname';
            break;
    }
    $this->clink = @mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->passwd);
    @mysql_select_db($this->database,$this->clink);         
 }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> $objConn = new mysqlconnect();
>   $Conn = $objConn->setobjConnect("localhost","root","P@ssw0rd");

Comment: You should expand a little bit your answer, just pasting raw code without nothing to say it's not helpful to who asked the question and to the community. If you want some guidance you can refer to the "How to write a good answer" on the Help Center. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -3):

```
class Database{
    var $last_query; //Saved result of the last query made
    var $last_result; //Results of the last query made
    var $func_call; //A textual description of the last query/get_row/get_var call
    var $link; //database link
    var $lastquery; //last query
    var $result; //query result

    // Connect to MySQL database
    function database() {
        $this->link=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Server connexion not possible.');
        //Set All Charsets to UTF8
        mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8 , character_set_client=utf8 , character_set_connection=utf8 , character_set_database=utf8 , character_set_server=utf8");
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die('Database connection not possible.');
    }
    /** Query the database.
      * @param $query The query.
      * @return The result of the query into $lastquery, to use with fetchNextObject().
      */
    function query( $query ){
        $this->lastquery=$query;
        $this->result=@mysql_query( $query, $this->link );
        return $this->result;
    }
    /** Do the same as query() but do not return nor store result.
      * Should be used for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE...
      * @param $query The query.
      * @param $debug If true, it output the query and the resulting table.
      */
    function execute($query)
    {
      @mysql_query($query);
    }
    /** Convenient method for mysql_fetch_object().
      * @param $result The ressource returned by query().
      * @return An ARRAY representing a data row.
      */
    function fetchArray($result){
    if ($result == NULL)
        $result = $this->result;
    if ($result == NULL || mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
        return NULL;
    else
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    /** Close the connecion with the database server.
      * It's usually unneeded since PHP do it automatically at script end.
      */
    function close()
    {
      mysql_close($this->link);
    }
    /** Get the number of rows of a query.
      * @param $result The ressource returned by query(). If NULL, the last result returned by query() will be used.
      * @return The number of rows of the query (0 or more).
      */
    function numRows($result = NULL)
    {
      if ($result == NULL)
        return @mysql_num_rows($this->result);
      else
        return mysql_num_rows($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
![<?php
class mysqlconnect{
private $server=null;private $user=null;private $password=null;private $objConnect=null;
function setobjConnect($s,$u,$p){
$this->server = $s;
$this->user = $u;
$this->password = $p;
return $this->objConnect = mysql_connect($this->server,$this->user,$this->password);
}
}
$objConn = new mysqlconnect();
$Conn = $objConn->setobjConnect("localhost","root","P@ssw0rd");
if($Conn)
    {
        echo "Database Connect";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Database Connect Failed.";
    }
mysql_close($Conn); 

?>]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Hl6.png)